# Форматирование текста через for

Tags: python, python-3.x

не могу понять как правильно напечатать текст

Хочу такое:

```
* |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F
--+------------------------------------------------
0 |  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
1 |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F
2 |  0  2  4  6  8  A  C  E 10 12 14 16 18 1A 1C 1E
3 |  0  3  6  9  C  F 12 15 18 1B 1E 21 24 27 2A 2D
4 |  0  4  8  C 10 14 18 1C 20 24 28 2C 30 34 38 3C
5 |  0  5  A  F 14 19 1E 23 28 2D 32 37 3C 41 46 4B
6 |  0  6  C 12 18 1E 24 2A 30 36 3C 42 48 4E 54 5A
7 |  0  7  E 15 1C 23 2A 31 38 3F 46 4D 54 5B 62 69
8 |  0  8 10 18 20 28 30 38 40 48 50 58 60 68 70 78
9 |  0  9 12 1B 24 2D 36 3F 48 51 5A 63 6C 75 7E 87
A |  0  A 14 1E 28 32 3C 46 50 5A 64 6E 78 82 8C 96
B |  0  B 16 21 2C 37 42 4D 58 63 6E 79 84 8F 9A A5
C |  0  C 18 24 30 3C 48 54 60 6C 78 84 90 9C A8 B4
D |  0  D 1A 27 34 41 4E 5B 68 75 82 8F 9C A9 B6 C3
E |  0  E 1C 2A 38 46 54 62 70 7E 8C 9A A8 B6 C4 D2
F |  0  F 1E 2D 3C 4B 5A 69 78 87 96 A5 B4 C3 D2 E1
```

Вышло так:

```
* |  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f 
--+---------------------------------
0 |  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 |  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f
2 |  0 2 4 6 8 a c e 10 12 14 16 18 1a 1c 1e
3 |  0 3 6 9 c f 12 15 18 1b 1e 21 24 27 2a 2d
4 |  0 4 8 c 10 14 18 1c 20 24 28 2c 30 34 38 3c
5 |  0 5 a f 14 19 1e 23 28 2d 32 37 3c 41 46 4b
6 |  0 6 c 12 18 1e 24 2a 30 36 3c 42 48 4e 54 5a
7 |  0 7 e 15 1c 23 2a 31 38 3f 46 4d 54 5b 62 69
8 |  0 8 10 18 20 28 30 38 40 48 50 58 60 68 70 78
9 |  0 9 12 1b 24 2d 36 3f 48 51 5a 63 6c 75 7e 87
a |  0 a 14 1e 28 32 3c 46 50 5a 64 6e 78 82 8c 96
b |  0 b 16 21 2c 37 42 4d 58 63 6e 79 84 8f 9a a5
c |  0 c 18 24 30 3c 48 54 60 6c 78 84 90 9c a8 b4
d |  0 d 1a 27 34 41 4e 5b 68 75 82 8f 9c a9 b6 c3
e |  0 e 1c 2a 38 46 54 62 70 7e 8c 9a a8 b6 c4 d2
f |  0 f 1e 2d 3c 4b 5a 69 78 87 96 a5 b4 c3 d2 e1
```

Код:

```
systema = int(input())

if(systema > 1 and systema <= 10):

    print("*", "| ", end = " ")
    for i in range(0, systema):
        print( i, end = " ")
    print()
    print("--+-", end="")
    for i in range(0,systema):
        print("--",end="")
    print()
    for i in range(0,systema):
        print(i, "| ", end='')
        for j in range(0, systema):
            print(' {}'.format(i*j), end='')
        print()

if(systema > 10):

    print("*", "| ", end = " ")
    for i in range(0, systema):
        print( hex(i)[2:], end = " ")
    print()
    print("--+-", end="")
    for i in range(0,systema):
        print("--",end="")
    print()
    for i in range(0,systema):
        print(hex(i)[2:], "| ", end='')
        for j in range(0, systema):
            print(' {}'.format(hex(i*j)[2:]), end='')
        print()
```

Comment: Попробуйте `print(' {:>2}'.format(hex(i*j)[2:]), end='')` в самом нижнем `for`е.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import string

digits = string.digits + string.ascii_uppercase

def tobase(b, x):
    return digits[x] if x < b else tobase(b, x // b) + digits[x % b]

def row(b, x):
    return ''.join(tobase(b, x * y).rjust(3) for y in range(b))

def table(b):
    print('* |' + row(b, 1))
    print('--+' + '-' * b * 3)
    for x in range(b):
        print(tobase(b, x) + ' |' + row(b, x))

table(16)
```

```
* |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F
--+------------------------------------------------
0 |  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
1 |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F
2 |  0  2  4  6  8  A  C  E 10 12 14 16 18 1A 1C 1E
3 |  0  3  6  9  C  F 12 15 18 1B 1E 21 24 27 2A 2D
4 |  0  4  8  C 10 14 18 1C 20 24 28 2C 30 34 38 3C
5 |  0  5  A  F 14 19 1E 23 28 2D 32 37 3C 41 46 4B
6 |  0  6  C 12 18 1E 24 2A 30 36 3C 42 48 4E 54 5A
7 |  0  7  E 15 1C 23 2A 31 38 3F 46 4D 54 5B 62 69
8 |  0  8 10 18 20 28 30 38 40 48 50 58 60 68 70 78
9 |  0  9 12 1B 24 2D 36 3F 48 51 5A 63 6C 75 7E 87
A |  0  A 14 1E 28 32 3C 46 50 5A 64 6E 78 82 8C 96
B |  0  B 16 21 2C 37 42 4D 58 63 6E 79 84 8F 9A A5
C |  0  C 18 24 30 3C 48 54 60 6C 78 84 90 9C A8 B4
D |  0  D 1A 27 34 41 4E 5B 68 75 82 8F 9C A9 B6 C3
E |  0  E 1C 2A 38 46 54 62 70 7E 8C 9A A8 B6 C4 D2
F |  0  F 1E 2D 3C 4B 5A 69 78 87 96 A5 B4 C3 D2 E1
```

Answer (score 3):

Просто укажите выравнивание в строке форматирования. В вашем случае до 3х символов

```
print('{:>3}'.format(hex(i*j)[2:]), end='')
```

`>` - по правому краю, < по левому, число - ширина столбца

Comment: Можно так: `print('{:>3X}'.format(i*j), end='')`